# How to get the next immediate following-sibling of the current processing element in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0 for transforming one xml file to another xml file.In XSLT 2.0, i created a function that takes one argument.Actually, the argument is a collection of `<w:p>` elements.So, in the function i am using `<xsl:for-each-group>` to get the each `<w:p>` and process one by one.Suppose, the below mentioned XML file contains one `<w:table`> elements between `<w:p>` elements.So, now i want to check `following-sibling::w:table` in the function after processing each `<w:p>` element in `<xsl:for-each-group>` block.

XML File

```
 <w:document>
      <w:p> para0</w:p>
      <w:p> para1</w:p>
      <w:table>table</w:table>
      <w:p>para3</w:p>
</w:document>
```

XSLT Snippet :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="w:p">           
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"> <!-- for processing <w:p>elements -->
                </xsl:apply-templates>         

                <xsl:if test="following-sibling::w:table"> <!--check following-sibling of current <w:p> is <w:table> -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w:table">    </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

But the check for `following-sibling::w:table` called when the first  elements processed.I will call only when second  element is processed.So, I want to check only next immediate `following-sibling` of the current processing element is  or not in that place...

So,Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: Please show some expected output from your sample input. Can the $paragraphs sequence contain other nodes other than p  and table? Or is it limed to p and table?

Comment: my $paragraphs contains only p. But xml document contains lot of other nodes too

Answer (score 0):

Within xsl:for-each-group, the context item is the first item in the current group. So following-sibling will select relative to the first item in the group. If you want to select relative to the second item, use current-group()[2]/following-sibling::x. (Also you probably only want the first following sibling, which would be following-sibling::x[1]).

But then you talk about the "current processing element" which is your own invented terminology. Do you want to process the following siblings of every item in the group? In that case I would expect to see an xsl:for-each select="current-group()" inside the xsl:for-each-group.

Comment: @ Michael Key : Sorry... I didn't get you. Each time for-each-group gets the <w:p> elements one by one.So, In my sample XML document i have three <w:p> elements and one <w:table> element.So, in the first iteration, i want to check if next element(immediate following-sibling) is <w:table> or not.If yes then i want to call some template for processing <w:table> elements,Otherwise don't do anything.So, in this case, next element is not <w:table> elements.So,don't do anything at this stage.But when the second iteration,the next element is(immediate following-sibiling) is <w:table>.

Comment: Continue...So, I have to call a particullar template by selecting the <w:table> element.This is my job...If your answered for this, then could you please explain more about your answer...

Comment: :Yes, i want to check if next immediate following-sibling is <w:table> and if yes then i want to call my template every time in the group...